# Same Route for Multiple Controllers/Pages

Tags: php, routes, laravel

I'm developing an ecommerce with Laravel. Here's what I'm stuck at:

This is what a category link may look like:

> mysite.com/category_name
>
> mysite.com/category_name*[/probable_sub_category_name]*

And this is what a product link may look like:

> mysite.com/product_name
>
> mysite.com*[/probable_category_name]**[/probable_sub_category_name]*/product_name

I set my routes like this:

```
Route::get(array('(:any)', '(:all)/(:any)'), array('before' => 'is_category', 'uses' => 'categories@index'));
Route::get(array('(:any)', '(:all)/(:any)'), array('before' => 'is_product', 'uses' => 'products@index'));
```

If I put product route in the first place, category links break and if I put category route in the first place, product links break, as expected. How can I use the same routing for both?

My PHP version is 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.4 (says phpinfo())

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer and then accept it 24 hours later as the correct answer so as to help clean up unanswered questions. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Jason. I hope I've done it right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The magic is Controller::call() method. Here is the solution:

```
Route::get(array('(:any)', '(:all)/(:any)'), function () {

    // Current URI as array
    $parameters = Request::route()->parameters;

    // Checks if given parameter is a product's url value
    $check_if_product = function ($parameter) {
        $products = Product::where('url_title', '=', $parameter)->count('id');
        return (is_numeric($products) && $products > 0 ? true : false);
    };

    // Checks if given parameter is a category's url value
    $check_if_category = function ($parameter) {
        $categories = Category::where('url_title', '=', $parameter)->count('id');
        return (is_numeric($categories) && $categories > 0 ? true : false);
    };

    // If last parameter from URI belongs to a product
    if ($check_if_product(end($parameters)))
    {
        return Controller::call('products@index');
    }
    // If last parameter from URI belongs to a category
    elseif ($check_if_category(end($parameters)))
    {
        return Controller::call('categories@index');
    }
    else
    {
        return Response::error('404');
    }

});
```

Comment: Method [call] does not exist.

Comment: The code was for Laravel 3. I think it became harder to accomplish the same functionality.